# Convergence in probability and probabilistic Big-O relation

Tags: probability, limits, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variables such that $X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} a$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then is it true that $X_n = a+O_p(|X_n - a|)$? If true, could anyone show me how to prove it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $O_p(|X_n-a|)$?

Comment: It means bounded in probability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation

Comment: From the definition on wikipedia of stochastic boundedness I don't see how there is any dependence on convergence. 

Fix $\epsilon > 0$, take $M=2$ and $N=1$, then
$$P\left(\left|\frac{X_n - a}{|X_n-a|}\right| > 2\right) = 0 < \epsilon,\quad\text{for $n\geq 1$}$$
so $X_n - a = O_p(|X_n-a|)$.